# JMSException for HornetQ in Wildfly 10

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I am running more than one schedulers at a time with 1000ms and 500ms repeatInterval. The schedular reads some messages from queue, processes them, and store in a MySQL database. In middle of these process sometimes I am getting this kind of exceptions.

```
javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ119014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71
2020-02-25 12:05:27,483 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:398)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,483 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:304)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,484 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.sendFullMessage(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:378)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,484 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.sendRegularMessage(ClientProducerImpl.java:286)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,485 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.doSend(ClientProducerImpl.java:264)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,485 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:122)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,485 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.doSendx(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:477)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,486 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:173)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,486 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at com.ecomm.web.jmsqueue.SubmitToJMS.sendJMSMessagewithpriority(SubmitToJMS.java:197)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,486 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at com.ecomm.web.jmsqueue.InputMsgNewServerQueue.sendtosenderQueue(InputMsgNewServerQueue.java:78)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,486 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at com.pl4sms.web.thread.InputMsgSchHighPriority.execute(InputMsgSchHighPriority.java:36)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,487 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,487 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
2020-02-25 12:05:27,487 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5) Caused by: ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ119014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71]
2020-02-25 12:05:27,488 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)        ... 13 more
2020-02-25 12:05:27,488 ERROR [com.ecomm.web.jmsqueue.SubmitToJMS] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5) javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ119014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71
```

Comment: Please add lots of context as to what you were trying to do, where you saw this error, etc. Also, what is your question?

Comment: You say you're sending a message to a HornetQ broker embedded in Wildfly 10, but Wildfly 10 doesn't embed HornetQ by default. It embeds ActiveMQ Artemis instead (which is based on the HornetQ code-base). Furthermore, the stack-trace indicates you're using the ActiveMQ Artemis JMS client. Can you please clarify the role that HornetQ is playing in your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe your problem at least a little. A CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT jut means that you can't connect which is some configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.      I am running more than one schedulers at a time with 1000ms and 500ms repeatInterval. The schedular reads some messages from queue. process them and store in mysql database. In middle of these process sometimes I am getting this kind of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `com.ecomm.web.jmsqueue.SubmitToJMS` is attempting to send a message, but this operation is timing out waiting for a response from the broker. You should either increase the time out on the client (e.g. by using the `callTimeout` parameter on the client URL, defaults to `30000` milliseconds) or investigate why the broker receiving the message isn't responding to the client within the allotted time.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. I had the same problem with camel routing.

**.transacted()** option removed this problem:

```
from("timer:hello?period=10s")
               .routeId("hello1")
               .transacted()
               .setBody(simple("This is plain string"))
               .to("jms:queue:consumerQueueName");
```

java 18 + wildfly 20 + artemis 2.25.0

all via JNDI